# Why does TableResult.collect works while Table.collect doesn't

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Flink 1.13.0 and I have following simple code snippet

```
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.scala.table2RowDataSet
import org.apache.flink.table.api.{EnvironmentSettings, TableEnvironment}

object HelloFlinkBatchTable {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val settings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().inBatchMode().useBlinkPlanner().build()
    val tenv = TableEnvironment.create(settings)


    val words = tenv.fromValues("hello", "world", "hadoop", "spark", "world").as("word")

    words.collect().foreach(println)

    words.printSchema()

    tenv.createTemporaryView("words", words)

    //collect works on TableResult
    val result = tenv.executeSql("select word from words")
    result.collect()


    //collect doesn't work on the Table
    //ERROR:Table cannot be converted into a DataSet. It is not part of a batch table environment.
    words.collect()

  }
}
```

I would ask why `TableResult.collect` works while `Table.collect` doesn't(The error is: `Table cannot be converted into a DataSet. It is not part of a batch table environment.`). I think I have specified the batch environment correctly in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicit conversion `table2RowDataSet` is actually deprecated but it is hard to deprecate implicit conversions in general.

The DataSet API is reaching end of life and will be fully integrated into `TableEnvironment` and `StreamExecutionEnvironment` in the mid term.

`TableResult.collect` is the official and stable supported way of retrieving results. Other implicits will be updated in Flink 1.14 see [FLINK-22590](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-22590).